# nvcc.exe linking error Microsoft Visual Studio configuration file 'vcvars64.bat' could not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda, nvcc

I want to use `nvcc -ptx` from windows command line, but I always get this error message:
nvcc : fatal error : Microsoft Visual Studio configuration file 'vcvars64.bat' could not be found for installation at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual S
tudio 11.0\VC\bin/../..'

I'm using vs 2012 express edition. What can be the solution?

Comment: Is your project set to 32-bit or is it set to 64-bit?

Answer (score 15):

I have managed to solve the issue and make work with MS Visual Studio Express 2012, here what I did:

2. Installed MS Visual Studio 2012 Express
3. Installed `cuda_5.5.20_winvista_win7_win8_general_64`, the latest version as of 2014-01-16
4. From this directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin`, I have copied x86_amd64 to amd64
5. In the new directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64`, I have created a file `vcvars64.bat`
6. In the file `vcvars64.bat`, just added: `CALL setenv /x64`

The compilation worked great:

```
C:\CUDA>nvcc -o square square.cu
    Creating library square.lib and object square.exp

C:\CUDA>square.exe
0.000000        1.000000        4.000000        9.000000
16.000000       25.000000       36.000000       49.000000
64.000000       81.000000       100.000000      121.000000
144.000000      169.000000      196.000000      225.000000
```

Comment: The (seemingly pointless) step of creating a copy of the `x86_amd64` directory and calling this copy `amd64` did it for me. I would never have found that out (the NVCC error message is not telling anything about this - instead, it suggests that it's looking for the `vcvars64.bat` in the Visual Studio base directory...)

Comment: This also worked for me, except for VS2010 I did not have to add an amd64 folder - it was already there so I just created the batch file in there and presto.

Comment: Worked for me too, first I was testing it by 'nvcc ?' which doesn't work, but the compile process worked for cuda.

Answer (score 2):

From [NVIDIA CUDA Compiler Driver](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#supported-host-compilers) document

> 1.2. Supported Host Compilers
> nvcc uses the following compilers for host code compilation:
>
> On Linux platforms
>
> The GNU compiler, gcc, and arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ for cross compilation to the ARMv7
> architecture
>
> On Windows platforms
>
> The Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, cl On both platforms, the compiler found on the current
> execution search path will be used, unless nvcc option -compiler-bindir is specified (see File and Path Specifications).

Answer (score -1):

Your visual studio install is asking for .NET v3.5 framework:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21

Got this info from this: [Where can I find Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542367/where-can-i-find-microsoft-build-utilities-v3-5)

Answer (score -2):

When in your project go to Configuration Properties > CUDA C/C++ > Device and change Code Generation to the following: compute_11,sm_11

Comment: This did not fix anything for me and gives a warning that they are deprecated.